# XNA 2D Game Camera doesnt work

Tags: c#, xna, camera, 2d

I'm making a zelda-like 2D Role-Playing-Game with XNA and wanted to implement a camera which follows the player today. Soo... I didn't really understand how it's working, but I found a nice code-example here: http://www.david-amador.com/2009/10/xna-camera-2d-with-zoom-and-rotation/
I implemented it and changed the spritebatch.Begin(); to what the guy in the thread said. Now it is working ... well. The collisions are alright and the player is centered (since I set the position of the camera to the position of the player once a frame) but: The textures don't get drawed the way they did before. So for example the shadow is drawn under the grass (=you can't see the shadows) the player is sometimes drawn over the NPCs and sometimes under them and the wall-tiles disappear and reappear like they want :(

Do I have to change the drawing-code or the order they get drawn?

Hope somebody know what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [Spritebatch.Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433989.aspx) call you can specify the layer depth.  When specifying the layer depth, you will need to use the proper [Sprite Sort Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx) when initializing your SpriteBatch.

Comment: Aah, now I understand :) Until now, I had to make the layer-things by myself^^ Thanks for the answer!